# Where isthis TensorFlow code going wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

So I wrote a code for a CNN, with a picture being of dimension (350, 1, 1000, 1) in NHWC format. Now the data is perfect, the network is running but the output is strange. Here is my code (probably no syntactical error but some logical error):

```html
weights_conv1 = tf.get_variable(name = 'wc1', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random_normal(shape = (1, 3, 1, 20), mean = 0, stddev = 1.0))
weights_conv2 = tf.get_variable(name = 'wc2', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random_normal(shape = (1, 3, 20, 20), mean = 0, stddev = 1.0))
weights_conv3 = tf.get_variable(name = 'wc3', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random_normal(shape = (1, 3, 20, 20), mean = 0, stddev = 1.0))
weights_conv4 = tf.get_variable(name = 'wc4', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random_normal(shape = (1, 3, 20, 20), mean = 0, stddev = 1.0))
weights_conv5 = tf.get_variable(name = 'wc5', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random_normal(shape = (1, 3, 20, 10), mean = 0, stddev = 1.0))

filters = [weights_conv1] + [weights_conv2] + [weights_conv3] + [weights_conv4] + [weights_conv5]

bias1 = tf.get_variable(name = 'b1', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random_normal(mean = 0, stddev = 1.0, shape = (1, 1, 1, 20)))
bias2 = tf.get_variable(name = 'b2', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random_normal(mean = 0, stddev = 1.0, shape = (1, 1, 1, 20)))
bias3 = tf.get_variable(name = 'b3', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random_normal(mean = 0, stddev = 1.0, shape = (1, 1, 1, 20)))
bias4 = tf.get_variable(name = 'b4', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random_normal(mean = 0, stddev = 1.0, shape = (1, 1, 1, 20)))
bias5 = tf.get_variable(name = 'b5', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random_normal(mean = 0, stddev = 1.0, shape = (1, 1, 1, 10)))

biases = [bias1] + [bias2] + [bias3] + [bias4] + [bias5]


def convolutionForwardPropagation(img, filters, biases):
    c1 = tf.nn.conv2d(img, filters[0], strides =[1,1,1,1], data_format ='NHWC', padding = 'VALID')
    f1 = tf.nn.relu(c1) + biases[0]
    c2 = tf.nn.conv2d(f1, filters[1], strides =[1,1,1,1], data_format ='NHWC', padding = 'VALID')
    f2 = tf.nn.relu(c2) + biases[1]
    
    c3 = tf.nn.conv2d(f2, filters[2], strides =[1,1,1,1], data_format ='NHWC', padding = 'VALID')
    f3 = tf.nn.relu(c3) + biases[2]
    c4 = tf.nn.conv2d(f3, filters[3], strides =[1,1,1,1], data_format ='NHWC', padding = 'VALID')
    f4 = tf.nn.relu(c4) + biases[3]
        
    c5 = tf.nn.conv2d(f4, filters[4], strides =[1,1,1,1], data_format ='NHWC', padding = 'VALID')
    f5 = tf.nn.relu(c5) + biases[4]
    
    shape = f5.shape
    fr = tf.reshape(f5,(shape[0], shape[3] * shape[2]))
    fc1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(fr, 1000, activation_fn = tf.nn.relu)
    fc2 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(fc1, 2, activation_fn = tf.nn.relu)
    print(fc2.shape)
    
    return fc2

fc = convolutionForwardPropagation(trainDataset, filters, biases)
entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits = fc, labels = labelsTrain, name = 'cross_entropy')
loss = tf.reduce_mean(entropy, name = 'loss')

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)

hypothesis = tf.nn.softmax(fc)
correct_preds = tf.equal(tf.argmax(hypothesis, 1), tf.argmax(labelsTrain, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(correct_preds, tf.float32))


writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./graphs/logreg', tf.get_default_graph())
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(0, epochs):
        sess.run(fc)
        _, l = sess.run([optimizer, loss])                 
        sess.run(hypothesis)
        sess.run(correct_preds)
        acc = sess.run(accuracy)
        print("Epoch :", i+1, ", loss : ", l, ", accuracy :", acc)
writer.close()
```

The result is kinda strange:

```html
(350, 2)
Epoch : 1 , loss :  599.7743 , accuracy : 175.0
Epoch : 2 , loss :  64824.633 , accuracy : 175.0
Epoch : 3 , loss :  15540.435 , accuracy : 175.0
Epoch : 4 , loss :  0.69314754 , accuracy : 175.0
Epoch : 5 , loss :  0.69314754 , accuracy : 175.0
Epoch : 6 , loss :  0.69314754 , accuracy : 175.0
Epoch : 7 , loss :  0.69314754 , accuracy : 175.0
Epoch : 8 , loss :  0.69314754 , accuracy : 175.0
.....
```

So what exactly is wrong in my code?

Comment: Out of curiosity: What value did you set your learning rate to?

Comment: Also would you care to explain what exactly ``correct_preds = tf.equal(tf.argmax(hypothesis, 1), tf.argmax(labelsTrain, 1))` is *supposed* to achieve? I'm assuming that this is where your error lies...

Comment: @dennlinger correct predictions? Also lr is 0.001

Answer (score 1):

You need to create placeholders for the input data and labels.

Then you need to use those placeholders as inputs to your functions and feed in values to those placeholders in sess.run().

Below is your code with the fixes.

```
eights_conv1 = tf.get_variable(name = 'wc1', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random_normal(shape = (1, 3, 1, 20), mean = 0, stddev = 1.0))
weights_conv2 = tf.get_variable(name = 'wc2', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random_normal(shape = (1, 3, 20, 20), mean = 0, stddev = 1.0))
weights_conv3 = tf.get_variable(name = 'wc3', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random_normal(shape = (1, 3, 20, 20), mean = 0, stddev = 1.0))
weights_conv4 = tf.get_variable(name = 'wc4', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random_normal(shape = (1, 3, 20, 20), mean = 0, stddev = 1.0))
weights_conv5 = tf.get_variable(name = 'wc5', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random_normal(shape = (1, 3, 20, 10), mean = 0, stddev = 1.0))

filters = [weights_conv1] + [weights_conv2] + [weights_conv3] + [weights_conv4] + [weights_conv5]

bias1 = tf.get_variable(name = 'b1', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random_normal(mean = 0, stddev = 1.0, shape = (1, 1, 1, 20)))
bias2 = tf.get_variable(name = 'b2', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random_normal(mean = 0, stddev = 1.0, shape = (1, 1, 1, 20)))
bias3 = tf.get_variable(name = 'b3', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random_normal(mean = 0, stddev = 1.0, shape = (1, 1, 1, 20)))
bias4 = tf.get_variable(name = 'b4', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random_normal(mean = 0, stddev = 1.0, shape = (1, 1, 1, 20)))
bias5 = tf.get_variable(name = 'b5', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random_normal(mean = 0, stddev = 1.0, shape = (1, 1, 1, 10)))

biases = [bias1] + [bias2] + [bias3] + [bias4] + [bias5]

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[350, 1, 1000, 1],name = "img_trainDataset")
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[dim1,dim2],name = "labelsTrain")

def convolutionForwardPropagation(X, filters, biases):
    c1 = tf.nn.conv2d(X, filters[0], strides =[1,1,1,1], data_format ='NHWC', padding = 'VALID')
    f1 = tf.nn.relu(c1) + biases[0]
    c2 = tf.nn.conv2d(f1, filters[1], strides =[1,1,1,1], data_format ='NHWC', padding = 'VALID')
    f2 = tf.nn.relu(c2) + biases[1]

    c3 = tf.nn.conv2d(f2, filters[2], strides =[1,1,1,1], data_format ='NHWC', padding = 'VALID')
    f3 = tf.nn.relu(c3) + biases[2]
    c4 = tf.nn.conv2d(f3, filters[3], strides =[1,1,1,1], data_format ='NHWC', padding = 'VALID')
    f4 = tf.nn.relu(c4) + biases[3]

    c5 = tf.nn.conv2d(f4, filters[4], strides =[1,1,1,1], data_format ='NHWC', padding = 'VALID')
    f5 = tf.nn.relu(c5) + biases[4]

    shape = f5.shape
    fr = tf.reshape(f5,(shape[0], shape[3] * shape[2]))
    fc1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(fr, 1000, activation_fn = tf.nn.relu)
    fc2 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(fc1, 2, activation_fn = tf.nn.relu)
    print(fc2.shape)

    return fc2

fc = convolutionForwardPropagation(X, filters, biases)
entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits = fc, labels = Y, name = 'cross_entropy')
loss = tf.reduce_mean(entropy, name = 'loss')

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)

hypothesis = tf.nn.softmax(fc)
correct_preds = tf.equal(tf.argmax(hypothesis, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(correct_preds, tf.float32))


writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./graphs/logreg', tf.get_default_graph())
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(0, epochs):
        _, l, h, c, a = sess.run([optimizer, loss, hypothesis, correct_preds, accuracy], feed_dict={X: trainDataset, Y: labelsTrain})                 
        print("Epoch :", i+1, ", loss : ", l, ", accuracy :", a)
writer.close()
```

As a general rule of thumb, try not to use multiple sess.run() but instead put everything you need to get inside one sess.run(). Calling sess.run() executes your whole graph everytime it is called and hence it is computationally expensive.

Comment: Actually my other nn not cnn , was working fine on this almost same code